# What's wrong with this Java HashMap declaration? Easy points

Tags: java, hashmap, declaration

```
private HashMap<String, IMapper> mapper = new HashMap<String, IMapper>();
```

Seems so innocent yet Eclipse is complaining about the semi-colon, of all things.

Eclipse error: Syntax error on token ";", invalid AssignmentOperator

Thanks

The entire class:

```
package persistence;

import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.HashMap;

import domain.Task;

public class PersistanceFacade {

    private static PersistanceFacade uniqueInstance = null;
    private HashMap<String, IMapper> mapper = new HashMap<String, IMapper>();


    (SingleTaskRDBMapper) mapper.put("SingleTask", new SingleTaskRDBMapper());

    public PersistanceFacade() {};

    public static synchronized PersistanceFacade getUniqueInstance() {
        if (uniqueInstance == null) {
            uniqueInstance = new PersistanceFacade();
            return uniqueInstance;
        }
        else return uniqueInstance;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Object get(UUID oid, Class type) {
        Object mappers;
        IMapper mapper = ((HashMap<String, IMapper>) mappers).get(type);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error that Eclipse reports?

Comment: You might also want to go to Eclipse options: Project -> Clean... , because sometimes some errors get stuck in Eclipse and you need to use that option to force it to completely refresh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
(SingleTaskRDBMapper) mapper.put("SingleTask", new SingleTaskRDBMapper());
```

is out of place. You should put that in the constructor:

```
public PersistanceFacade() {
  mapper.put("SingleTask", new SingleTaskRDBMapper());
}
```

Also notice I removed the extraneous semicolon after the closing brace of the constructor. I'm also not sure what is going on in the get method. You declare the object `mappers` but never initialize it. That will certainly cause an error.

Comment: thank you for helping me realize that mapper.put statement should go into the constructor. That closes this ticket :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what IMapper is, some interface I assume, but I just dropped this into Eclipse and it doesn't give me any errors:

```
private interface IMapper {}
private HashMap<String, IMapper> mapper = new HashMap<String, IMapper>();
```

Perhaps you could post more of your code?

Answer (score 1):

This code works perfectly :), inspired by help from laz

```
package persistence;

import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class PersistanceFacade {

    private static PersistanceFacade uniqueInstance = null;
    private HashMap<String, IMapper> mappers = new HashMap<String, IMapper>();

    public PersistanceFacade() {
        mappers.put("SingleTask", new SingleTaskRDBMapper());

    }

    public static synchronized PersistanceFacade getUniqueInstance() {
        if (uniqueInstance == null) {
            uniqueInstance = new PersistanceFacade();
            return uniqueInstance;
        }
        else return uniqueInstance;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Object get(UUID oid, Class type) {
        IMapper mapper = (IMapper) mappers.get(type);
        return mapper.get(oid);
    }

}
```